# Ryzen iGPU connected to display, NVIDIA dGPU connected to HDMI, how to use NVIDIa GPU for inbult display, Parrot OS

Tags: graphics, nvidia, amd-processor, parrot-os

I have recently discovered that my NVIDIA GTX1650TI is not being used for graphical processing to my main display, instead my Ryzen 5 5000 series iGPU is. Would I be able to use my NVIDIA GPU as my main one for my main display (in-built monitor).

I have tried:

1. Installing NVIDIA Drivers
2. Editing X11/Xorg config files
3. Reinstalling
4. Adding `nvidia-primary.conf` to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` (this works with the HDMI port but doesn't output anything to display as NVIDIA isn't connected to in-built display, Ryzen is)

NVIDIA-PRIMARY.conf CONTENTS:

```
        Identifier "nvidia"
        MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
        Driver "nvidia"
        Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
        Option "SLI" "Auto"
        Option "BaseMosaic" "on"
        Option "PrimaryGPU" "yes"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier "layout"
        Option "AllowNVIDIAGPUScreens"
        Option "PrimaryGPU" "yes"
EndSection
```

5. and messing around with NVIDIA Prime

what should I do?
My specs are as follows:
Laptop: HP Pavilion 15-ec2051AX
Graphics Card: NVIDIA GTX1650
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 5600H
RAM: 32GB
Storage: 512GB NvME SSD

Comment: wrong site for this as it has nothing to do with programming but deals with configuring LINUX ...

Comment: Sorry, my bad i'll post it somewhere else.